# Wondering if this is typo at EURONEWS chanel now in their subtitle

Tags: word-meaning

This is the exact copy of breaking news now broadcast on Euronews TV. There's a word -Conclevesily! Is this a typo? If yes what could be the correct word?

> Investigators had 'conclevesily' ' stablished that one of the pilots or someone else had with flying experience had hijacked the plane, unnamed Malaydian government official said.

Comment: Can you get us a link. I could not find this phrase anywhere on the Internet. Also, there's a typo *This is...* :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a typo. It could be *conclusively*. Also, there is another problem in the sentence.

> *"Investigators had conclusively established that one of the pilots or someone else with flying experience had hijacked the plane,"* unnamed [sic] Malaysian government official said.

Comment: @StoneyB yes but it wasn't in the reference. Though I added as a *[sic].*